# After updating Android Studio 4.1, codes are shown in white color

Tags: android, android-studio

After I updated my Android Studio to 4.1 my code glance is like below
[image]

and mostly the code text is white. I want to get all codes colorful.

Comment: Have you tried invalidate caches/restart?!

Comment: yes, many times. Moreover I have tried clean project / rebuild

Answer (score 0):

Install the flutter plugin on android studio

preferences > plugins

worked for me.... and restart android studio